# Paul’s Encounter

Tags: acts, paul, chronology

Is there any historical evidence to date around what time Paul encountered Jesus? I’ve heard it said that he acually encountered him in 37 AD when Jesus m was still alive (granted, I’m pretty sure, this was from a individual who thinks Paul is a false apostle).

> And as he journeyed, he came near Damascus: and suddenly there shined round about him a light from heaven (Acts 9:3)

When did this event happen?

Comment: Hi Bertram, I added a verse to the question so it doesn't get closed as out of scope for the site. Feel free to edit further if you don't like the changes I made.

Answer (score 2):

The precise year is unknown, but if we're willing to make a few reasonable assumptions from the historical data, we can define a pretty narrow range of possible years.

**The historical record**

Paul provides relevant information in his epistle to the Galatians and he declares it under oath to people who could fact-check him, so this is pretty secure historical testimony.

1. Paul speaks of his conversion (Gal. 1:15-16)
2. Paul went to Jerusalem 3 years after his conversion:

> Then after three years I went up to Jerusalem to see Peter, and abode with him fifteen days. (Gal. 1:18)

3. Paul visited Jerusalem again after 14 years

> Then fourteen years after I went up again to Jerusalem with Barnabas, and took Titus with me also. (Gal. 2:1)

--

**The assumptions to consider**

It is unclear if the 14 years in Gal. 2:1 is counting from his conversion or from his prior visit to Jerusalem...so Paul could be saying this visit was 14 years or 17 years after his conversion.

The meeting described in Gal. 2 aligns extremely well with the Jerusalem Conference of Acts 15, which is generally dated to AD 49. There's an outside chance it's not the Jerusalem Conference, but a meeting prior to Paul's first missionary journey, circa AD 46.

Paul does not appear to be counting inclusively, but in an effort not to over-specify an answer, we should at least consider that inclusive counting is possible.

--

**Earliest & Latest possible dates**

Using the data above, the latest possible date for Paul's conversion would assume:

- Gal. 2 describes a conference in AD 49
- The 14 years in Gal. 2:1 count from Paul's conversion, not his prior visit to Jerusalem
- Paul is counting inclusively, so "14 years" means that 13 years have elapsed and it's now the 14th year

AD 49 - 13 = **AD 36** (latest possible date)

The earliest possible date for Paul's conversion would assume:

- Gal. 2 describes a conference in AD 46
- The 14 years in Gal. 2:1 count from Paul's prior visit to Jerusalem, which was itself 3 years after his conversion
- Paul is not counting inclusively, so "3 years" and "14 years" mean that 17 years have elapsed.

AD 46 - 17 = **AD 29** (earliest possible date)

So that gives us a range of dates for Paul's conversion from AD 29 to AD 36. However, we can rule out AD 29 on separate evidence (this was before Easter and Paul's experience on the road to Damascus was after Easter).

--

**A Best Guess**

From my own study of the Pauline chronology I come to the following tentative conclusions:

- Gal. 2 describes a conference in AD 49
- The 14 years in Gal. 2:1 count from Paul's conversion, not his prior visit to Jerusalem
- Paul is not counting inclusively

Best estimate then would be AD 49 - 14 = Paul's conversion occurred in **AD 35**

---

Notes

Assigning a date of AD 49 to the Jerusalem Conference is a reasonable conclusion but it's a lengthy chronological exercise to demonstrate why--this would be best suited to a question specifically dedicated to this matter. If we wanted to be extremely chronologically cautious, we could say the conference occurred in AD 49 +/- 1 year

The year of the crucifixion & Easter is itself a matter of some debate. The most popular answers are AD 30, 31, 33, and 34. You'll find very capable defenders of distinct answers on this site. It was definitely before AD 37, by which point Pilate was no longer in office. My own work on the subject is available on my YouTube channel [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGACqQS4ut5jZnDaAdEpShgbkiyttyMa1).

Comment: You have left very little room for controversy here. Excellent answer, + 1. It's great that you have included your "YouTube" link (under notes), which as you already know, I myself viewed (among others) quite some time ago and concurred with, which also leaves very little room for controversy, as to the year and actual date, not to mention time, of Jesus' death. All visitors/posters to BHSE would do well to check you out on YouTube, of that I have no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The best historical evidence comes from Paul himself, who states:

1 Corinthians 15

> I handed on to you as of first importance what I also received: that
> Christ died for our sins in accordance with the scriptures; 4 that he
> was buried; that he was raised on the third day in accordance with the
> scriptures; 5 that he appeared to Cephas, then to the Twelve. 6 After
> that, he appeared to more than five hundred brothers at once, most of
> whom are still living, though some have fallen asleep. 7 After that he
> appeared to James, then to all the apostles. 8 Last of all, as to one
> born abnormally, he appeared to me. 9 For I am the least of the
> apostles, not fit to be called an apostle, because I persecuted the
> church of God.

This indicates that Paul dates his experience with Jesus to well after Jesus' death and resurrection. The exact date is uncertain. [This timeline](https://jesusalive.cc/timeline-jesus-death-pauls-conversion/) puts it at six years after the crucifixion, placing the encounter at around 35 c.e. Some commentators make it a few years earlier. The OP's date of 37 c.e. does not seem plausible if Jesus is thought not to have died yet. (Is this a typo? 27 c.e. is plausible since many believe Jesus was born around 4 b.c.e.)  But unless Paul is lying, it cannot be prior to Jesus' crucifixion. It is plausible that Paul met Jesus earlier, but not in the sense of the encounter mentioned here and elaborated upon in the Book of Acts.